# Custom Validator Not Showing Error Message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, customvalidator

On my Domain Model for my ASP.net MVC3 application I have built a custom validator to ensure the date of birth is inserted in a particular format.

I am saving the date of birth as a string, because my application needs to save the date of birth of long dead people, e.g. Plato, Socrates, etc., just in case you were wondering why not use `DateTime` to save date of birth.

Here is my custom validator code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class ValidateDODDOB : ValidationAttribute
{
    // Error Message
    private const string DefaultErrorMessage = "Please type the date in the format specified.";

    // Gets or sets the Regular expression.
    private Regex Regex { get; set; }        

    // The pattern used for Date of Birth and Date of Death validation.
    public string Pattern { get { return @"^(?:\d+\s)?(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)?(?:\s?\d+)(?:\sBCE)?$"; } }

    // Initializes a new instance of the VerifyDODDOB class.
    public ValidateDODDOB() : base(DefaultErrorMessage)
    {
        this.Regex = new Regex(this.Pattern);
    }

    // Determines whether the specified value of the object is valid.
    // true if the specified value is valid; otherwise, false.
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        // convert the value to a string
        var stringValue = Convert.ToString(value);

        var m = Regex.Match(stringValue);

        return m.Success;
    }
}
```

The above works in terms of validating, and stopping the Create/Edit Actions from proceeding through to the database. But no error message is being displayed when the form is returned to the View!

**UPDATE IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT 01:**

Sorry Olive, I should have posted the view code too. Here it is:

```
<div class="inputField">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.DOB, "Date of Birth")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DOB)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOB)
</div>
```

So Yes, I have told it to to show the Validation message as well. And as far as AJAX, it is not via AJAX. Like you said, it is after a full POST Request.

Comment: Does your view code use @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PropertyWithValidateDODDOBAttribute)? Can you post your view code? Also, are your Create/Edit actions accessed over AJAX? Or is the validation message not being displayed after a full POST request?

Comment: Could you post your controller and model as well? Could be some small issues such as not annotating the DOB in the model with ValidateDODDOB attribute, or missing ModelState.IsValid in the controller, etc. It definitely helps posting them as well.

Comment: Here is [the code](http://pastebin.com/CheimsUA) for handling the HttpPost request in the Controller. As for the Model, it sits in an External project, and looks [like this](http://pastebin.com/sYJCEKrr). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want the message to show in a ValidationSummary control?

If so, try setting the "excludePropertyErrors" of the ValidationSummary HtmlHelper to false:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

This will tell the summary control to summary display all errors (having it set to 'true', the default value, will tell the control to display model-level errors only).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are probably wanting to do is use this method

```
 protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
{

    // convert the value to a string
    var stringValue = Convert.ToString(value);

    var m = Regex.Match(stringValue);

    if(!m.Success)
    {
        return new ValidationResult(DefaultErrorMessage);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then in your view make sure you have the ValidationMessageFor, and in the Controller make sure you check **ModelState.IsValid** and return the original View if it is not valid. That ought to do it.

Comment: I've just tried it with code above, but I get the error: [cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'public' inherited member 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.IsValid(object) ] !!

Comment: Oops, forgot the ValidationContext, try it now... If that doesn't work , trying switching protected to public

Comment: Thanks I tried your amended code, it compiles fine, but again the error message on validation does not show :(

Comment: Did you try just the [RegularExpression(@"^(?:\d+\s)?(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)?(?:\s?\d+)(?:\sBCE)?$")] attribute?

Comment: Do you have the jQuery Validation files in your view?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6069/discussion-between-jcreamer898-and-ciwan)